# If the text-box value in HTML5 form is x, then y: Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, html

So basically, I want to enter a certain string into a text-box, and check what it is. It's basically for a command system that I'm trying to implement. There's a little Terminal pop-up and there is a text-box in it waiting for a command. This is the HTML I used to make the text-box inside a form:

```
<form id="command-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Command" id="command-box">
    <input type="submit" style="display: none">
</form>
```

I made the submit invisible so you could press enter and it would submit the form. Here is the JavaScript I'm using:

```
function changeStyle(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('specific-sheet').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}

var command = document.getElementById('command-input');

if(command.value=="windows"){
    changeStyle('../css/windows-xp.css');
}
```

I want to make it to where if I type "windows" into the command box and hit enter, it will change my stylesheet. The people on this website are smart, so I once again am asking for help. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Don't use JavaScript as your validation. Use server-side script because users can always change/see your JS code on the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to check with an event. Assuming this is in the plain  tags;  you can use the following:

```
var inputbox = document.getElementById('command-input');

function changeStyle(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('specific-sheet').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}

inputbox.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    if (this.value == 'windows'){
       changeStyle('../css/windows-xp.css');
    }
});
```

Edit:

you can do this as well. Change the event to "onsubmit" if you want enter key to trigger.

```
function changeStyle(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('specific-sheet').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}

document.getElementById('command-input').addEventListener(
  'keyup',
  function(eve){
      if (eve.target.value == 'windows'){
       changeStyle('../css/windows-xp.css');
    }

  },
  false
);
```

If you want to keep the changes even after the page refresh you might have to keep the file path in the localstorage and use that in dom load event.

Also, you really dont need to wrap this in a form tag. You can use a simple div and this is not triggered by a form submit.

Comment: you need to wrap up these in an anonymous function.

Comment: the code is updated. Please check the edited one. should work

Comment: please approve the answer if it worked for you. @HarrisonReeves

Comment: It still doesn't work, but I might know why. After I submit the form it reloads the page instantly, so it might be changing it and then reloading, losing the change.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that you can call on form submission as explained here at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp.

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var command = document.getElementById('command-input');

if(command.value=="windows"){
    changeStyle('../css/windows-xp.css');
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: So I would change my form to <form id="command-input" onsubmit="checkCommand()"> and put my var and if inside a function checkCommand() along with all the other commands I want--correct?